# Which way is the best to check data exist in database?

Tags: database, compare

Which way is the best to check data exist in database?
When the data has multiple value (EX: personal = Name, phone, address)

A: use the sql query, select count(*) from table where t.Name='Name' 
and t.phone = phone.....

B: read database to get the rows then use the for loop to check every value in row

when database is large ?
when database is small ?
Even need to check multiple data at once?

Comment: my opinion A, and it's not like a `SO` question, my friend

Comment: Even need to check multiple data at once?

Answer (score 0):

Its almost always better to use a SQL query if available, as not only are they very fast, but also it will be the best system to use if the database scales up and becomes much larger.  Reading a database and then looping through the results takes a lot longer and is much more performance intensive, so as a general rule it is to be avoided unless its absolutely needed, it should be avoided.  Saying that however it does have a few advantages such as storing the results in variables etc if they will be frequently needed.

Without any more info about what you're trying to do, an example of querying the database and then checking the number of rows returned in php would be :

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Name, Phone from table where table.Name='Name' and table.phone = 'phone'")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Even need to check multiple data at once?